# iOS PhoneGap 2.3 Config.xml Confusion

Tags: ios, cordova

Okay so I am trying to port my Android app that is currently using PhoneGap over to iOS. In the Android world I used the config.xml file to store settings such as splash screen and screen timeout along with icon urls. The issue I am having is how do I get this to work on iOS in xcode? In the sample PhoneGap project from Adobe they state that the cordova.plist file is gone in 2.3 and is replaced by config.xml, but then adobe goes and states that the config.xml file is used for the Adobe PhoneGap App Builder. Where do I store my settings if I dont want to use the App Builder? I have the packages installed correctly, because my app loads fine, but I cannot seem to change any of the splash screen or timeout settings. Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you want to update your splashscreen.
You should replace the defaults png files via xCode finder in the left side of the workspace.
Then, just clean and rebuild.

Comment: I have the splash screen working fine through the iOS project settings. The question I have is where do I store the PhoneGap settings that use to be in the cordova.plist file? In this project (https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap) with the newest version 2.3 they got rid of the cordova.plist file?

Comment: PhoneGap 2.3 use config.xml file instead of, but if you migrating from lower version, you should use the upgrade script